# push duplicate values into array based on length provided

Tags: javascript

I want to insert duplicate values into array based on length provided like this:

```
var a = ['bar', 'google', 'mod'];
var b = [];

var dataLength = 4;
```

output should look like: `var a = ['bar', 'bar','bar','bar', 'google', 'google', 'google', 'google', 'mod', 'mod','mod', 'mod'];`

I tried this:

```
var dataLength = 4;
var a = ['bar', 'google', 'mod'];
var b = new Array(dataLength);
var c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    c.push((b.fill(a[i]).toString()))
}
```

It works but not sure this is a good way to do this.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is `b` for?... Anyway.. https://jsfiddle.net/a6poy31x/

Comment: @ScottSauyet may be `var dataLength = 4 * a.length;` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create duplicate objects into array based on length provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554633/create-duplicate-objects-into-array-based-on-length-provided)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const a = ["barclays", "google", "vod"];

const result = (num) => a.reduce((acc, ele) => acc.concat(Array(num).fill(ele)), []);

console.log(result(10))
```

Comment: Actually I have an object instead of array: `var a = [{displayName: 'bar'}, {displayName:'google'}, {displayName:'mod'}];`

Comment: @kittu, in your case, change fill(ele)  to fill(ele.displayName)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = ['barclays', 'google', 'vod'];
var b = [];

var dataLength = 4;
// Loop every element of a
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  // Loop 4 times and push current element
  for (let j = 0; j < dataLength; j++) {
    b.push(a[i])
  }
}

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add nested for loop, loop through your data length and push the element in your array.

```
var a = ['barclays', 'google', 'vod'];
var b = [];

var dataLength = 4;

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   for(let j=0;j<dataLength;j++) {
     b.push(a[i])
   }
}
```

Comment: Too slow bro! :D

Comment: I was just kidding because your solution is exactly as mine. But sorry for the joke, have an upvote as well!

Answer (score 1):

Two of our newest Array methods, flatMap() and fill() are perfect for this:

`.flatMap()` will do a mapping and merge the returned arrays into one array.
`.from()` can create a new array for a specific length.
`.fill()` fills an array with a certain value.

So all 3 combined we get this little oneliner:

```js
var a = ['barclays', 'google', 'vod'];
var length = 4;
var b = a.flatMap( word => Array.from({ length }).fill( word ));

console.log( b );
```

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple technique is just to use `flatMap` with `Array.prototype.fill`:

```js
const repeatN = (n, arr) => arr .flatMap (a => Array (n) .fill (a) )

console .log (
  repeatN( 4,  ['barclays', 'google', 'vod'] )
)
```

If your environment doesn't [support `flatMap`](https://caniuse.com/#search=flatmap), it's not hard to shim, or you could use this instead:

```js
const repeatN = (n, arr) => 
  arr.map(a => Array (n) .fill (a)) .reduce ( (a, b) => a .concat (b) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = ['barclays', 'google', 'vod'];
var b = [];

var dataLength = 4;

for (let i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
   for (let o = 0; o < a.length; o++){
       b.push(a[o]);
   }
}

console.log(b);
```

Something like this,except in my example its not sorted.