# create duplicate objects into array based on length provided

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to insert duplicate values into array based on length provided like this:

```
var a = [{displayName: 'bar'}, {displayName:'google'}, {displayName:'mod'}];;
var dataTypesLength= 4;
```

Output should be like:

```
var a = [{displayName: 'bar'},{displayName: 'bar'},{displayName: 'bar'},{displayName: 'bar'}, {displayName:'google'},{displayName:'google'},{displayName:'google'},{displayName:'google'}, {displayName:'mod'}, {displayName:'mod'}, {displayName:'mod'}, {displayName:'mod'}];
```

I tried this:

```
a = a.flatMap( word => Array.from({ dataTypesLength}).fill( word ));
```

but I am getting typescript error saying: `Argument of type '{ dataTypesLength: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dataTypesLength' does not exist in type 'ArrayLike<{}>'`

Comment: Start with something simple and something you can cope with: eg with 2 nested loops, one iterates the `a`, the other iterates `1..4` and pushes items from `a`. This is a straightforward and naive solution. As long as you have it working - you can see if you can turn it into composition of functions.

Comment: That object is not an array like - it has a `dataTypesLength` property, not a `length` property...

Comment: @zerkms it's also a solution [OP knows about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544880/push-duplicate-values-into-array-based-on-length-provided/56544944#56544944)

Answer (score 2):

Just loop the array of objects and use `fill` to get your result.

```js
var a = [{displayName: 'bar'}, {displayName:'google'}, {displayName:'mod'}];
var dataTypesLength= 4;
var arr=[];
function fillArray(value, len) {
  return Array(len).fill(value);
}
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  var b = fillArray(a[i],dataTypesLength);
  arr.push(...b);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` with `Object.assign` so that each object will have independent reference

```js
var a = [{displayName: 'bar'}, {displayName:'google'}, {displayName:'mod'}];
var dataTypesLength= 4;

a= a.map(obj => { return Array(dataTypesLength).fill(null).map( e => Object.assign({}, obj)) }).flat();
console.log(a)
```

Comment: one small thing. each set of objects are in different arrays. I think OP needs in same array

Comment: We can use `Array.flat()`. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use this (single line solution):

`a.reduce((acc,x)=>{ acc.push(...new Array(dataTypesLength).fill(x)); return acc;}, [])`

Explaination :

- Reducing the input array starting from empty array []
- For every element creating a new array with length dataTypesLength and filling all the new array with the current element ***new Array(dataTypesLength).fill(x)***
- Spread the new created array and push it into accumulator array ***acc.push(...new Array(dataTypesLength).fill(x))***
- Return the accumulator array

Answer (score 0):

you can try `reduce`

```
var a = [{displayName: 'bar'}, {displayName:'google'}, {displayName:'mod'}];;
var dataTypesLength= 4;

a  = a.reduce(
(f,obj ) => {
var dup = new Array(dataTypesLength); 
f.push(...dup.fill(obj));
return f;
}, [] )
```